# Not able to import any python library in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, gnome-terminal, 20.04

First when I tried importing libraries after installing them prompt said **"module not found"** afterwards, error showing that module **_ctypes** not found and I am not able to install that also. Please help me!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some modules need to be installed with `apt` or, say, `synaptic`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Worked for me at least for numpy:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.2 (default, Mar 13 2020, 10:14:16) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.pi
3.141592653589793
>>> exit()
```

By the way, we have different versions of python and gcc...

Comment: Still I am not able to import it as the same error as in the image is showing; which is **not able to import _ctypes**. Also I am not able to install _ctypes?

Comment: Also when i run the sudo commands to update python and gcc it shows to the newest version that are 3.8.2 and 9.3.0 respectively. But when i run the versions become 3.8.0 and 7.4.0

Comment: Normally python (and libs) reside under /usr , not /home . What do `whereis python` and `which python3` say?